# Why does my toast not display on my emulator?

Tags: android, calendar, toast

I have a very basic pqctice app working with a CalendarView.  I'd like a toast to display the date when a different date than the current is called. The main activity displays fine and the view works, but the toast does not display at any point. What am I missing?

My MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDateChangeListener {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

base = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
date = base.getDate();

base.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        if(base.getDate() != date) {
            date = base.getDate();
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), month + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

}

The XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.practice.andrea.whysoobsessedwithcalendars.MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.practice.andrea.whysoobsessedwithcalendars.MainActivity"
        >

        <CalendarView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Again should be really basic stuff. I''m not sure why it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd try this: `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, month + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your toast.I tried your code and the problem is if block.It never gets executed.If you comment the if block then your toast runs.Just change the logic related to change in date.